# better form for mean of subset data

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a data set :

```
    X     Y
   20     12
   24     11
   12      7
   10      2
   41     24
   13      9
   50     17
    4     12
   17     12
   35     19
```

Now i have to find the mean of Y when 20 < X < 50.

My attempt:

```
     data <- data.frame(X=c(20,24,12,10,41,13,50,4,17,35),
                        Y=c(12,11,7,2,24,9,17,12,12,19))
     sub <- subset(data,X>20 & X<50)
     mean(sub$Y)
```

Is there any direct way to find the mean of Y when 
20< X<50 without modifying the original data frame ,ie, without subset it?

Comment: `mean(data[abs(data[,"X"]-35)<15,"Y"])`

Comment: Or `with(data, mean(Y[20 < X & X < 50]))`. @JakeBurkhead, You could post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "without subset it". At some point you are going to have to subset the data in some way since you are looking for the mean of a subset of the data. If you mean "don't call the subset function and save another copy of the data" you can just do

```
mean(data$Y[data$X > 20 & data$X < 50])
# [1] 18
```

Answer (score 4):

Or, using `data.table` for its syntactic sugar:

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(data)
 DT[X>20 & X <50,mean(Y)]
 [1] 18
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `data.table`. So i tried `?data.table` but it's saying `No documentation for ‘data.table’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??data.table’
> ??data.table
> 
` and then no result found. Could you please tell me where am i doing mistake?

Comment: @harry I edit my answer.You should install `data.table` package.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have installed `data.table`.It's working. But when i write the command `library(data.table)` it gives `warning`  `data.table 1.8.8  For help type: help("data.table")
Warning message:
package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 2.14.2 
`